# How to make a button link to another html page?

Tags: gwt

How to make a button link to another html page?

```
button.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {

public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
  //this code has to redirect to another page within the project
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The question is tagged as GWT so based on that... to do it entirely on the client, you can use the `com.google.gwt.user.client.Window` class.

```
Window.open(linkURL, "_self", "");
```

[Here's a link to the docs](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.0/com/google/gwt/user/client/Window.html).

Answer (score 4):

Look under gwt javadocs for the Window class.
There are some static members in the Window class.

The open function is the same as that in javascript:

```
Window.open(url, targetFrame, features )
```

In GWT, "_self" is the name of the current active display frame/window.

Location replace, just as in javascript:

```
Window.location.replace(url)
```

Display alert or confirm window:

```
Window.alert(msg)
Window.confirm(msg)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted a button but not in the script you can try this:

```
<a href="//Wherever your page is//">YOUR PAGE</a>
<a href="https://stackoverflow.com/">Stack Overflow</a>
```

Answer (score -1):

No need to use JS. As of HTML5, buttons support the `formaction` attribute where you can specify the URL.

```
<form>
    <button formaction="http://stackoverflow.com">Go to stackoverflow!</button>
</form>
```

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button#attr-formaction